# Very dark screen in live USB session with lenovo laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, usb, lenovo

I am trying out Ubuntu on a Lenovo laptop with a live USB. The USB also has Ventoy installed onto it.

When I boot into Ubuntu, everything goes fine up until I use the "Try Ubuntu" option. The screen will flash for a second and go to the desktop but everything is very dark or black with some red. I'm kind of able to use it but it is impossible to see anything.

I tried to install drivers through safe mode but it did not work. I've also used the official website to download the .ISO.

The USB I'm using is an EMTEC 16 GB USB flash drive. I’ve also tried using budgie with the same results.

Video demonstration of what’s going on: https://youtu.be/7T7-ZECJ4wM

Here's the specs for the laptop I'm using:

```
CPU: Intel(R) Celeron(R) 1.60GHz  
RAM: 3.9 GB  
SSD: SanDisk DB4064
```

Comment: I don't know exactly but it's just the main laptop screen, so it might be an Intel adapter since it doesnt have a GPU in it.

Comment: I’ll record a video of me booting into the live desktop environment and test it. This has also happened to me in another ubuntu “flavor” where instead I’m able to see blue and red and see the mouse but same problems.